# Scraping Yahoo Finance with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a complete newbie in scraping and I'm trying to scrape https://fr.finance.yahoo.com and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My goal is to scrape the index name, current level and the change(both in value and in %)  [image: Indexes]

Here is the code I have used:

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://fr.finance.yahoo.com'

request = urllib.request.Request(url)

html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')


main_table = soup.find("div",attrs={'data-reactid':'12'})
print(main_table)

links = main_table.find_all("li", class_=' D(ib) Bxz(bb) Bdc($seperatorColor) Mend(16px) BdEnd ')
print(links)
```

However, the `print(links)` comes out empty. Could someone please assist? Any help would be highly appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the better way to get all the fields is parse and process the relevant script tag, this is one of the ways you can get all them.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/'

r = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Index Name','Current Level','Value','Percentage Change'])

for item in soup.select("[id='market-summary'] li"):
    index_name = item.select_one("a").contents[1]
    current_level = ''.join(item.select_one("a > span").text.split())
    value = ''.join(item.select_one("a")['aria-label'].split("ou")[1].split("points")[0].split())
    percentage_change = ''.join(item.select_one("a > span + span").text.split())
    df = df.append({'Index Name':index_name, 'Current Level':current_level,'Value':value,'Percentage Change':percentage_change}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Output are like:

```
        Index Name Current Level     Value Percentage Change
0           CAC 40       4444,56     -0,88            -0,02%
1    Euro Stoxx 50       2905,47      0,49            +0,02%
2        Dow Jones      24438,63    -35,49            -0,15%
3          EUR/USD        1,0906   -0,0044            -0,40%
4      Gold future       1734,10     12,20            +0,71%
5          BTC-EUR       8443,23    161,79            +1,95%
6   CMC Crypto 200        185,66      4,42            +2,44%
7      Pétrole WTI         33,28     -0,64            -1,89%
8              DAX      11073,87      7,94            +0,07%
9         FTSE 100       5993,28    -21,97            -0,37%
10         Nasdaq        9315,26     30,38            +0,33%
11         S&P 500       2951,75      3,24            +0,11%
12      Nikkei 225      20388,16   -164,15            -0,80%
13       HANG SENG      22930,14  -1349,89            -5,56%
14         GBP/USD        1,2177   -0,0051            -0,41%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :-) The one thing I don't understand is the line: "for item in soup.select("[id$='MarketSummary-Proxy'] li"):" Where does the "Proxy" come from ? I couldn't find it in the HTML.

Comment: Okay, I've changed that id name for you to find that when you inspect element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fix your element selection.

For example the following code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://fr.finance.yahoo.com'

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

main_table = soup.find(id="market-summary")

links = main_table.find_all("a")
for i in links:
    print(i.attrs["aria-label"])
```

Gives output text having index name, % change, change, and value:

```
CAC 40 a augmenté de 0,37 % ou 16,55 points pour atteindre 4 461,99 points
Euro Stoxx 50 a augmenté de 0,28 % ou 8,16 points pour atteindre 2 913,14 points
Dow Jones a diminué de -0,63 % ou -153,98 points pour atteindre 24 320,14 points
EUR/USD a diminué de -0,49 % ou -0,0054 points pour atteindre 1,0897 points
Gold future a augmenté de 0,88 % ou 15,10 points pour atteindre 1 737,00 points
 a augmenté de 1,46 % ou 121,30 points pour atteindre 8 402,74 points
CMC Crypto 200 a augmenté de 1,60 % ou 2,90 points pour atteindre 184,14 points
Pétrole WTI a diminué de -3,95 % ou -1,34 points pour atteindre 32,58 points
DAX a augmenté de 0,29 % ou 32,27 points pour atteindre 11 098,20 points
FTSE 100 a diminué de -0,39 % ou -23,18 points pour atteindre 5 992,07 points
Nasdaq  a diminué de -0,30 % ou -28,25 points pour atteindre 9 256,63 points
S&P 500 a diminué de -0,43 % ou -12,62 points pour atteindre 2 935,89 points
Nikkei 225 a diminué de -0,80 % ou -164,15 points pour atteindre 20 388,16 points
HANG SENG a diminué de -5,56 % ou -1 349,89 points pour atteindre 22 930,14 points
GBP/USD a diminué de -0,34 % ou -0,0041 points pour atteindre 1,2186 points
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following `css` selector to get all the links.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://fr.finance.yahoo.com'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
links=[link['href'] for link in soup.select("ul#market-summary a")]
print(links)
```

**Output**:

```
['/quote/^FCHI?p=^FCHI', '/quote/^STOXX50E?p=^STOXX50E', '/quote/^DJI?p=^DJI', '/quote/EURUSD=X?p=EURUSD=X', '/quote/GC=F?p=GC=F', '/quote/BTC-EUR?p=BTC-EUR', '/quote/^CMC200?p=^CMC200', '/quote/CL=F?p=CL=F', '/quote/^GDAXI?p=^GDAXI', '/quote/^FTSE?p=^FTSE', '/quote/^IXIC?p=^IXIC', '/quote/^GSPC?p=^GSPC', '/quote/^N225?p=^N225', '/quote/^HSI?p=^HSI', '/quote/GBPUSD=X?p=GBPUSD=X']
```